# SSH : connection refused after installing freenx

Tags: networking, server, ssh, freenx

I had my server with Ubuntu-3.10-X64 with working connection and ping; then I installed **FreeNX server** on my server; then I restarted.

After that I couldn't connect to my server from my laptop using `ssh` and command line ; even remmina says ssh connection refused.
because this happened after the FreeNX server I think that FreeNX takes my ssh hostage and refuses the connection.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

That was a problem with my IP address. turns out there were another machine with the same IP as mine. (**Broadcast IP** was shared between two machine).
and because of that the ssh connection and in relation the NX connection was refused.